# How to write a file to an array of unsigned char, and write the data back to another file?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, vector

My attempt is as follows:

```
BYTE rgbPlaintext[] = {0x00};

std::ifstream in;
std::vector<char> contents;

in.open("test.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

if (in.is_open())
{
    // get the starting position
    std::streampos start = in.tellg();

    // go to the end
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);

    // get the ending position
    std::streampos end = in.tellg();

    // go back to the start
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // create a vector to hold the data that
    // is resized to the total size of the file    

    contents.resize(static_cast<size_t>(end - start));

    // read it in
    in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());

    BYTE *rgbPlaintext =  (BYTE*)&contents[0] ;
}


        in.close();

        std::ofstream f("testOut.dat",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        for(std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = contents.begin(); i != contents.end(); ++i) 
        {
             f << *rgbPlaintext;
        }
```

I used a vector of `char` because when I used `unsigned char` for the vector "contents" there was an error on the ampersand in the "read it in" step saying that an argument of type `unsigned char *` is incompatible with an argument of type `char *`. There was an error message in the "begin" method and under the `!=` in the writing of the file step as well, regarding conversion. When I leave the code as is, with the vector of type `char` in the file that is generated, there is just a bunch of nulls when I open it in Notepad++. In another question I posted, I was told that I have a scope issue with the code because the line `BYTE *rgbPlaintext =  (BYTE*)&contents[0] ;` is inside the if condition so it overwrites the one declared first. However, when I removed the `BYTE *` in front of it, I get an error saying: `Expression must be a modifiable value`

In summary, basically what I want to know is how to read a file into a BYTE[], where BYTE is a typdef for an unsigned char that is defined in a included header file WinDef.h, and then write the resultant BYTE[] to another file. The reason for this is so that I can pass the BYTE[] to methods that accept and modify it, but before that, I want to get the entry and exit of the data working correctly at least. And a summary of my attempt is :

1. Read file in binary mode into a vector of `char`
2. Convert to a vector of unsigned char <- Did not work
3. Write the data in binary mode to another file <- Resulted in nulls after changing the vector type back to `char`

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to define `BYTE`. If it's defined by a library, you forgot to tell which library you're using.

Comment: But generally, this `&contents[0]`  is not how you use a vector (or maybe you can, but it is not idiomatic) -- just allocate a char buffer for that.

Comment: BYTE is defined in an included header file WinDef.h which is from Microsoft, it is an unsigned char

Comment: @ITWorker put the relevant information into the question.

Comment: I take it you already know that `BYTE *rgbPlaintext =  (BYTE*)&contents[0];` shadows the outer-declared `rgbPlaintext`, leaving it as-is. if that isn't *really* the case, then please post **real** code.

Comment: As I already stated in my question, I am aware the code is shadowed. And I also stated what happens when I remove the shadowing, i.e. remove the BYTE * part in the inner declaration - I get an error. Expression must be a modifiable value. I have already stated this in the original question. This is the real code as I have it in my computer right now.

Comment: Ok.You also already know that the outer variable isn't a pointer; It's an array, which by definition is non-assignable, thus your error message. And the reason your file is filled with nullchar's is obvious since that is all you ever write to the file (the dereferenced global).  Something [like **this**](http://pastebin.com/VgaV902x) shoud get you the file in memory. Writing the file is a little different.

Comment: Write version would look something [like **this**](http://pastebin.com/bQ7C7jk3)

Comment: I will try those and see what happens, thanks.

Comment: I get errors on the LoadFile method: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' and std::vector<_Ty>' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: @ITWorker I take it you're not using a C++11 compliant compiler. [Then use these](http://pastebin.com/HCMqnsqw).